# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified

Tags: java, oracle, null, sql-update, clob

**How can I update records in my database?**

I work with db in **Oracle**. I have the table with columns RQUID(VARCHAR), STATUS(VARCHAR) and XMLDATA(**CLOB**). I want to update records in this table by RQUID. When I update STATUS and XMLDATA, things are good. When xmlData=**null**, I want to set null to XMLDATA in table, but in the line `int rows = pstmt.executeUpdate();` I get next message:

`[WARN] 2020-08-11 10:46:54,038 [pool-2-thread-1]  com.example.dao.AbstractDAO closeCLob - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified`

and my program freezes. Also the record is not updated. Can you have any suggestions, how to force my program to update records in both cases: when xmlData="someData" and when xmlData=null?

My code:

```
public boolean updateRecord(String rqUid, Integer code, String xmlData) throws MyException {
    if (rqUid != null) {
        String sql = "UPDATE MY_TABLE SET STATUS=?, XMLDATA=? WHERE RQUID=?";
        try (Connection con = pool.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareCall(sql)) {
            pstmt.setString(1, (code != null) ? code.toString() : null);
            pstmt.setString(2, xmlData);
            pstmt.setString(3, rqUid);
            int rows = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            return rows > 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = "Ошибка обновления записи";
            LOGGER.info(errorMessage, e);
            throw new MyException(errorMessage + ".", e);
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [explicitly set it to null](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull-int-int-):

```
if (xmlData == null || xmlData.length() == 0) {
    pStmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.CLOB);
}
else {
    pstmt.setString(2, xmlData);
}
```

Comment: I haven't meet `pStmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.CLOB);` yet. Nice solution. Thaaank you!

Answer (score 1):

When the field XMLDATA is null, you should update the table like this

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE  SET XMLDATA = EMPTY_CLOB();
```

I think you might add a new String sql when XMLDATA is null

```
String sql = "UPDATE MY_TABLE SET STATUS=?, XMLDATA=empty_clob() WHERE RQUID=?";
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not that, what I want. `EMPTY_CLOB()` sets empty value, but I need null value.